# How to get which TD has maximum width in TABLE in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, max, width

I want to get TD which has maximum width as compared to all other TDs in TR in Jquery or Javascript. I have mentioned in width to any TD or TR. Right now width of TDs are adjusted by text inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
var max = 0;    
    $('table td').each(function() {
        max = Math.max($(this).width(), max);
    }).width(max);
```

Demo Link - http://jsfiddle.net/oqt5j7zy/1/

Answer (score 1):

The value of `maxWidth` after running this code fragment will give the width of the `td` with the maximum width.

```
var maxWidth = -1;
$('tr td').each(function() {
    maxWidth = maxWidth > $(this).width() ? maxWidth : $(this).width();
});
```